# I am having significant trouble getting items to post a read News items in the time line

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-feed

I can't seem to get a post to work for our news items as FB News items. I was able to create a whole custom type and I discovered the News specific option after I had implemented a standard object:action setup successfully so conceptually this should work since we had all the pieces working before.

Originally we (GlobalPost) created out own app and Auth for our own name space gp_storyshare for our article object with a action read.

Then I ran over this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/news/
and sighed, since it wasn't linked to any of the other documentation and started over. Here is where I'm at.

Since then I have added in all the news specific OG tags and altered our og type to

without any name space

see good example page with tags here

http://www.globalpost.com/dispatch/news/regions/asia-pacific/111206/burma-myanmar-aung-san-suu-kyi

I have not done anything to our App, not sure if I need to make any auth changes or anything as the developer page says nothing and the object isn't mine to control. ** I have a feeling this is the issue but no real proof.**

on window.load I call newsRead() seen below, like I did before. This doesn't work.

```
function newsRead()
{
    FB.api('/me/news:reads' + 
                '?article=http://www.globalpost.com/$node->path','post',
                function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
```

I just have no idea what to try next. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any of the open graph actions (including built-in) you'll need the `publish_actions` permission, but it's still in beta at the moment and will only work for registered developers and testers of the app - I'm not aware of any other specific restrictions, but I think you're probably going to be posting 'Article' objects ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/ )